# PHP unable to output echo with text break \n in multi-list

Tags: php, html

I am working on a multi-select list for PHP pages, however, I have a problem with the multi-list when i select the text and it appear it in the wrong order as it has no wrap or text break on the each item
Here is a code I wrote in PHP

```
<select id="SKUproduct2" class="form-control input-sm listbox-height" multiple="multiple" rows=2>
    <option value="">
        <?php 
            if(isset($_POST['select_sku_list'])){ 
                $getInput = $_POST['select_sku_list']; 
                $selectedOption = "";
                foreach ($getInput as $option => $value) {
                    $selectedOption .= $value.","; // I am separating Values with a comma (,) as i have put /n or <br> which it not working()
                }
                echo "$selectedOption"."\n";
            }?>
    </option>
</select>
```

Here is a screenshot as result in the SKU Selected PHP pages as it does not list as I would like them in the break every list same as "list SKU to Select" rather than one line.

I am sure it a tiny tweak code that I might overlook it

[image]

Comment: You need to write your html `option` tags inside the loop. With the correct value and text content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting everything in a single option. This is not how HTML select works. Read here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

You need to `echo` additional `<option>` for each item in the list.

Like:

```
foreach ($getInput as $option => $value) {
    echo '<option>' . $value . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: So Embarrassed myself right now, I got fixed it, I should know better.